# Create password readable from PHP verify_password() in vb.net

Tags: php, vb.net, authentication, bcrypt

I have an app in vb.net and I want to store a password in my database that is understandable from PHP. The creation in PHP is like this:

```
$hash = password_hash("mypassword", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

The result looks like this:

```
$hash = '$2y$07$BCryptRequires22Chrcte/VlQH0piJtjXl.0t1XkA8pw9dMXTpOq';
```

and the code in php to validate a password looks likethis

```
if (password_verify('mypassword', $hash)) {

    echo 'Password is valid!';

} else {

    echo 'Invalid password.';

}
```

How can I replicate this code

```
$hash = password_hash("mypassword", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

iv VB.Net, so the results will match exactly?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the php password_hash documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), this function is using either BCrypt or Blowfish as the hashing algorithm. It looks like you're using the former. There is a [BCrypt library available for .Net on Github](https://github.com/BcryptNet/bcrypt.net), and perhaps other options on NuGet. You'll need to experiment with it to format the output to match php.

Additionally, the documentation says `password_hash()` embeds a randomly generated salt value as part of the returned hash. You must look [elsewhere in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.password.storing-salts) to see how this is formatted. It indicates the salt is the first 22 characters following the third `$`, with the actual hash comprising the remainder of the string. Everything before the third `$` indicates the algorithm and cost factor. I suggest reading the entire document from the link in this paragraph.

What's left is to know how the salt is combined with the original password prior to hashing. I saw some indication it is appended to the end of the password, but you'll want to validate this yourself. Example #3 from the first link in the first paragraph also has useful information, indicating that php would accept the result of the following as a valid salt: `mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)`.